# Populate the tabs and the form in each tab dynamically

Tags: json, extjs, dynamic, panel, tabbed

I am extracting data from the server and from that data I need to create the number of tabs and populate the data in the form of each tab.

For e.g.:
If my data has two fields named 'x' and 'y' then I need to create two tabs (where the form panel, meaning the fields inside the tab, are same) and then I need to populate these fields with the appropriate data.

Populating the data is fine but I need to know how to add tabs dynamically according to the JSON object I get. The name of the tab I'll be getting from the JSON object.

**EDIT**:
The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    ..
    events : {
        'X JOINED' : {
            ..
        }
        'Y JOINED' : {
            ..
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need two tabs named 'X JOINED' and 'Y JOINED' with the '..' giving the data to populate inside the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `tabpanel` you can use the method `add` to add a new tab.

To know the names of your object, just use the js `keys` method on your object obtained from JSON.

It will look something like that :

```
for(var prop in myObject)
    myTabPanel.add(Ext.define("tab", {title: prop}));
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have an sample of your JSON object?

Comment: I have given a sample JSON Object for you to consider.

Comment: Look at this link maybe it can help you : https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?109607-JSON-data-template-in-Tabpanel